How would I store and recover a file on a noisy connection such as a cassette tape, using command line tools like tar?
As a personal project, I'm trying to store and recover files from audio cassettes. It seems like the tar (tape archive) program must be designed with this in mind, given its name and history. But it doesn't seem to be able to do what I want.
Here's my workflow so far. I have some large file, like Moby_Dick.txt. First I create error correction codes with par2.
par2 create -s512 Moby_Dick.txt

This creates the files Moby_Dick.txt.par2 and Moby_Dick.txt.vol0+1.par2. Combined, these will allow me to recover the original data if some of it is damaged.
Next I combine everything into a single tar file:
tar -cf outgoing.tar Moby_Dick.*

This creates outgoing.tar. Now I want to transmit that file through an audio interface using some sort of common encoding. The best program I've found for this so far is Minimodem, which can transmit an arbitrary byte stream using the Bell 202 encoding. First I press "record" on the tape player, then:
cat outgoing.tar | minimodem --tx 1200

After a few minutes, this finishes. I rewind the tape and read the file back in:
minimodem --rx 1200 > incoming.tar

Already I'm having my first problem; minimodem has no way to know when the tape is done. So I rewind the tape and this time I monitor the output:
minimodem -q --rx 1200 | tee incoming.tar

Okay, so far so good, I wait until new bytes stop appearing and then I stop the tape. Now I have the file incoming.tar which is almost the same as my original file, but with some errors in it due to the unreliable medium. That's fine though, I can fix the files later using par2, so even if they're corrupted I still want to extract them.
tar -tf incoming.tar

This produces this output:
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

If I open the file in nano I can guess what's wrong -- there's extra bytes before and after the tarfile. But that's normal for magnetic tape, right? It seems like a tape archive program should have a way to skip to the first good header. And it looks like tar tried to do that, it even says Skipping to next header right there! But if I manually delete the junk bytes before the first header, and then run that command again:
Moby_Dick.txt
Moby_Dick.txt.par2
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Now tar is able to find the first file. But I had to "skip to the next header" myself -- when tar tried it earlier it just gave up! Is there a way to "force" tar to read as many files as it can, even if it has to skip over corrupted ones? Is there a better tool than tar that I should be using for literal tape archiving?

You're confusing a (audio) storage medium with a transmission method. Cassette tape was never a serious storage medium for computers. At best it was used by early adopters of home computers, e.g. pre IBM PC. "Tape archiving" should be performed with a tape transport (& controller) intended as a computer peripheral, rather than an audio device. None are inexpensive.

@sawdust, that makes sense. Tar isn't expecting to deal with tape noise, its expecting a dedicated piece of hardware to sit between itself and the tape, right? So I need to add an additional layer between tar and minimodem that emulates the functions a dedicated peripheral would perform. Does that already exist?

Tape noise is not the real issue. For HDD, SSD, and similar devices, the fundamental unit of data transfer (with the host computer) is a sector. For a tape device (i.e. the tape drive/transport plus its controller) the fundamental unit of data transfer is a block. The tape would be stopped or at rest. A read or write of a tape block would cause the controller to move the tape at proper speed to perform the read or write operation, and then stop the tape. The tape must only move when directed by the controller, i.e. when commanded by the computer.

"Does that already exist?" - I recall seeing a description of a suitable cassette transport+controller (w/SCSI interface?) circa 1980s. It had dual-capstan drive, probably copied from a high-end audio design. Can't imagine many were made and sold. There were better tape cartridges available (e.g. quarter-inch QIC) by then albeit at higher cost.

@sawdust, I meant does an emulator for that already exist? Some sort of command line utility that takes a tar file as input and produces some sort of packets on stdout? I'm not picky about the packet format, something like ham radio AX.25 or UDP, I'm still reading about this. It seems likely that something exists in software, but I dont know where to look.

You fail to understand the requirements for a computer tape drive. The tape must start moving to access each block (of an arbitrary length) and then stop moving. On the tape will be blocks of data and a gap between each pair of blocks. But your audio cassette deck cannot be controlled to start&stop by a computer. So it has to be used in streaming mode. You manually start the tape, then run a program to continuously read or write until you're done. Then you stop the tape. Your scheme can't tell the difference between reading "data" versus a (start) "gap", which is normally performed by HW.
